# Adding new items to the list when scroll from bottom to top in React causing the scroll to move down when a new item is added to the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I am having a list of 12 chapters for a book which is handled in 2 different scenarios.By default on page load it loads the first two chapters and it is stored in the state like below

chapters = [1, 2]

**Scenario 1: Scroll from top to bottom**
When the user scroll the chapters and reaches the star of second chapter it will check whether the 3rd chapter is available in the list. If it is not available then it will load chapter3 and update the state to [1, 2, 3] similarly it happens for 12 chapters [1, 2, 3, ... , 12].

Also there is an option for the user to choose a chapter from the menu which will fetch that chapter as well as it's previous chapter and next chapter and adds it in the state.

Example if the user selects chapter 5 it loads the chapter 5 at first then chapter 4 and then chapter 6 in the array like below [4, 5, 6].

**Scenario 2: Scroll from Bottom to Top**
Now the user chooses the last chapter and since it doesn't have any previous chapter it loads the previous chapter as well [11, 12]. When the user scrolls from 12th chapter to 11th chapter in the middle of 11th chapter it will check whether it has the previous chapter that is 10 in list.

At the time of adding the 10th chapter to the list and at the same time if the user is scrolling to top it cause a layout shift which makes the page to show the 12th chapter instead of 11th chapter when the 10th chapter is loaded in [10, 11, 12]

How can i avoid this layout shift when i scroll from bottom to top.

Here is my code.

## Parent component

```
<ChaptersPlaceholder
  sectionIds={sectionIds}
  chapters={chaptersData}
  onChapterReachedMiddle={chapterReachedMiddle}
/>
```

## Child component

```
const ChaptersPlaceholder: FunctionComponent<ChaptersPlaceholderProps> = ({
  chapters,
  sectionIds,
  onChapterReachedMiddle,
}) => {
  const [chapterGuides, setChapterGuides] = useState<ChapterData[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const uniqueData = uniqBy(chapters, (chapter: ChapterData) => {
      return chapter.title;
    });
    const sortedChapterData = uniqueData.sort(sortData);
    setChapterGuides(sortedChapterData);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [chapters]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const middleScroll = window.innerHeight / 2;
      chapters.forEach((chapterData: ChapterData) => {
        const chapterElement = document.getElementById(chapterData.url);
        if (chapterElement) {
          const rect = chapterElement.getBoundingClientRect();
          const elementMiddle = rect.top + rect.height / 2;
          if (elementMiddle >= 0 && elementMiddle <= middleScroll) {
            onChapterReachedMiddle(chapterData.url);
          }
        }
      });
    };

    // Attach scroll event listener
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // Cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [chapters, onChapterReachedMiddle]);

  const sortData = (a, b) => {
    const aIndex = sectionIds.indexOf(a.url);
    const bIndex = sectionIds.indexOf(b.url);

    return aIndex - bIndex;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {chapterGuides.map((chapterData: ChapterData, index: number) => {
        const chapterDataFields = chapterData?.data?.fields;
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            id={chapterData.url}
            className={cx('chapterguide__placeholder')}>
            {Object.keys(chapterData.data).length > 0 && (
              <MainChapterComponent
                name={''}
                rendering={chapterData.data as any}
                fields={{ ...(chapterDataFields as any) }}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```